# What happened to ETB on September 14

Tags: foreign-exchange

I'm not an economics perofessional, but I understand currency exchange rates are calculating based on economic stands.

On the 14th of September, 2018 the currency exchange rate for Ethiopian Birr (ETB) dipped to 14 ETB for 1 USD. It was 27 ETB for 1 USD before and after that day.

What are the possible causes for such a dip and how can I find out?

[image: ETB Exchange rate for the past month]

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a data glitch. [This chart](https://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=USD&to=ETB&view=1W) does not show the same spike:

[image]

Comment: What kind of data glitch? How does data flow?

Comment: You'd have to ask Google. I have no idea how they process data. It's not uncommon, though.

Comment: Just noting that the OP's chart is scaled from 10-30, so the dip goes way down (below 20).  The chart in this answer is only scaled 27.45-28.20, so the "big" variation around September 12th ought to be scarcely visible on the original chart.  That threw me for a minute.